# How to set email body content using string variable in blat.exe?

Tags: email, batch-file, blat

when I call below line of code in my batch file it successfully sends an email with email body content available in success_msg.txt.

```
C:\\MyPath\\blat.exe C:\\MyPath\\success_msg.txt -subject "This is Subject Line" -to user@abc.com
```

Is there any way to send a string variable in place of path of the content file?

Comment: Please explain your question.to my understanding you want to use variable to store data instead of a file is it?

Comment: yes @Justaus3r, the data is stored in a variable and would like to use that to send as EMAIL body content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"C:\MyPath\blat.exe" -body "Body text inline" -subject "This is Subject Line" -to user@abc.com
```

worked for me. The documentation appears to say that `-body` should itself be preceded by `-`  and also appears to require the body-text to be the first parameter.

I found that the `-`  before `-body` was not required, but did not test with the in-line body-text in any other position. YMMV.

I altered and quoted the executable-string. Doubling the `\` does nothing, and it must be quoted if the string contains spaces. (actually, `blat.exe` is located on my `path`, so the absolute-filename for the executable is not required, only `blat`)

The quoted-bodytext could be replaced by a variablename if desired, in the form `"%mybodytext%"`

My version : `v3.2.16 (build : Aug  7 2016 22:51:52)`

Comment: Thanks. I was using older version and -body wasn't available. Downloaded new one and it worked.